# How to get all available shipping method of a quote

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I am creating an extension which will remove one shipping method if another one is available.

For that i need to know all of available shipping method for that current quote!

How can i get that??

In rewrite shipping class i am using this code which removing shipping very well. But i want to remove this is free shipping is avilable

My code

```
<?php 
class Karmick_Hideshipping_Model_Shipping_Shipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
{
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        if (!$this->_isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)) {
           return $this;
        }
        return parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $carrierCode
     * @param Varien_Object $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAvailable($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        $regionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode();
        switch ($carrierCode) {
            case 'tablerate':
                return FALSE;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get what you want? @Asish Hira

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()
```

Work for me. also you find help from here.

[Get Shipping Method](http://blog.mage-express.com/magento-shipping-method-quote/#.Vw4vbvl97cs)

Comment: Thanks but it not working. i am overriding class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping`

Comment: can i know what is error?

Comment: after adding this i am not able to go on the checkout next step!  I gave my addresses on billing fields then click on `continue`. It not going to next step

Comment: hey you need to shipping method or payment method?

Comment: Because in your question says need to payment and your code for shipping.

Comment: I need shipping method! thanks for pointing me my fault

Comment: try this : Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod()

Comment: its return all shipping from the quote

Comment: Same problem! again stuct on billing address

Comment: where is you put this?

Comment: On the code i paste on my question!

Comment: maitri.infosys add me on sky

Comment: Thanks for the id! Here skype is not working! will send you once i open my laptop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38330/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-asish-hira).